# Why can't we invoke a delegate instance with ignored optional arguments?

Tags: c#

```
using System;

namespace Notes
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Foo(int x, int y = 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("x: {0} and y: {1}", x, y);
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Action<int, int> f = Foo;
            f(2, 4);
            //f(2); // cannot be invoked
        }
    }
}
```

Why can't we invoke a delegate instance with ignored optional arguments?

Comment: `f += MyNonOptionMethod;` Now what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why can't we invoke a delegate instance with ignored optional
>   arguments?

Because Action delegate is not declared with optional parameters. Declare your own delegate to do that.

```
delegate void MyAction<T1, T2>(T1 t1,T2 t2 = default(T2));

void Main()
{
    MyAction<int, int> f = Foo;
    f(2, 4);
    f(2);
}

static void Foo(int x, int y = 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("x: {0} and y: {1}", x, y);
}
```

Comment: I like answers and comments with examples that I can understand. :-)

Answer (score 4):

The compiler has no idea what method(s) your delegate holds.

If you want to use optional parameters, you need to declare the *delegate* as having optional parameters.
Beware that optional parameters are baked into the callsite by the compiler; it will use the default value of the delegate, no matter how the underlying method(s) are declared.

Answer (score 0):

Because there's no compile-time indication that the delegate instance stored in `f` takes an optional argument. You could determine this at runtime, but that would be a violation of C#'s type safety system.